# sqlachemy Many to Many: remove is not working and delete is too much

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, many-to-many, flask-sqlalchemy

I am working on a project including to link two class: User and Group.
A user can be in some groups, and each group can have some users.

So, I created a third table : group_guest, to hold user_id and group_id.
When I create user1, user2, group1 and group2, I can add to user1 the group1 and the group2.
And add to user2 the group1

Issue: then I cannot remove only the group1 from user1 
And delete group1 is not fine : user2 has no more group :/

I have tried almost every combinaisons: cascade, backref, delete orphan...
If someone as an idea... Should I modify the model ?
I would be gratefull !

code:

```
from app import db  
from flask_login import UserMixin  

group_guest = db.Table('group_guest',  
                       db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id')),  
                       db.Column('group_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('group.id'))  
                       )


class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)

    group_guest_group_id = db.relationship(
        "Group",
        secondary=group_guest,
        back_populates="group_guest_user_id",
        cascade="all, delete",
        lazy='dynamic'
    )


class Group(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    entitled = db.Column(db.String(64))

    group_guest_user_id = db.relationship(
        "User",
        secondary=group_guest,
        back_populates="group_guest_group_id",
        lazy='dynamic'
    )
```

Then :

```
user1.group_guest_group_id.remove(group1)
db.session.commit()
user1.guested_group().all()
```

It should (in my mind) return only group2 but it return the both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you want an asymmetric relationship across your table:

- If you delete a `User` then obviously all `user-group` secondary references to that `User` should also be deleted, i.e. cascaded in the secondary table.
- But you do not want to be able to delete a `Group` if at least one `User` is present in the group, deleting an active `Group` raises an integrity error.

In that case you can try the following:

```
group_guest = db.Table('group_guest',  
                   db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), primary_key=True),  
                   db.Column('group_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('group.id', ondelete='RESTRICT'), primary_key=True)
                   )

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)

    group_guest_group_id = db.relationship("Group",
        secondary=group_guest,
        back_populates="group_guest_user_id",
        passive_deletes='all', lazy='dynamic'
    )


class Group(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    entitled = db.Column(db.String(64))

    group_guest_user_id = db.relationship("User",
        secondary=group_guest,
        back_populates="group_guest_group_id",
        passive_deletes='all', lazy='dynamic'
    )
```

Passive deletes prevents SQLAlchemy from auto-executing cascading deletions and the Database low-level instructions specified by 'ondelete' of the foreignKey dictate the action directly.

Since the primary key on the secondary table cannot be NULL then you cannot delete the parent `Group` anyway. I just like the `ondelete='Restrict'` line since it explictly states the rules and can be easier to maintain/debug later on if you ever revisit it.

#### edited

the following works for me without issue:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
import uuid

Base= declarative_base()

group_guest= Table('group_guest', Base.metadata,
    Column('user_id', Integer, ForeignKey('user.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), primary_key=True),
    Column('group_id', Integer, ForeignKey('group.id', ondelete='RESTRICT'), primary_key=True))

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = Column(String(64), index=True, unique=True)

    group_guest_group_id = relationship("Group",
        secondary=group_guest,
        back_populates="group_guest_user_id",
        passive_deletes='all', lazy='dynamic'
    )

class Group(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'group'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    entitled = Column(String(64))

    group_guest_user_id = relationship("User",
        secondary=group_guest,
        back_populates="group_guest_group_id",
        passive_deletes='all', lazy='dynamic'
    )


e = create_engine("sqlite://")
Base.metadata.create_all(e)

s = Session(e)

u1 = User(username='A')
u2 = User(username='B')
g1 = Group()
g2 = Group()
s.add_all([u1, u2, g1, g2])
s.commit()

u1.group_guest_group_id.append(g1)
u1.group_guest_group_id.append(g2)
g1.group_guest_user_id.append(u2)
g2.group_guest_user_id.append(u2)

s.add_all([u1, u2, g1, g2])
s.commit()

u1.group_guest_group_id.remove(g1)
s.add(u1)
s.commit()

print([group for group in u1.group_guest_group_id])
print([group for group in u2.group_guest_group_id])
```

Comment: Hi Attack68,    

Thank you for the insigh and it's more logical with the restrict !  
But " user1.group_guest_group_id.remove(group1)"  still failed to remove the group1 from user1. ("user1.guested_group().all()" still equal [bet1, bet2])  
While in the mean time, if I remove() again group1, I got an error:  

"exc.StaleDataError:DELETE statement on table 'bet_guest' expected to delete 1 row(s); Only 0 were matched"
You have an other idea I willing to try it !

Comment: The code I have added works for me without a fault so besides missing an `add()` session command yours seems identical.

Comment: Aye, my function guested_group() was bad too, thank you for the help it works now !

Comment: @oliv7 please accept the answer if it solved the prob and works!